# Identity map of linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra

The projection map $\pi_1: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $$\pi_1(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,0), \ \forall (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb R^2$$

Prove if $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is a map such that $T^2=T$, then $T=0$ or $T = I$ (the identity map) or there is a basis $B$ for $\mathbb R^2$ such that $[T]_B = A$, where A is the matrix representation for $\pi_1$.

I need help with this problem: I've been thinking to consider the image of $T$ and use the kernel-image theorem. For example, start by proving that if there exists a linear map $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $T^2 = T$ and $dim \ Im(T)=2$, then $T$ is an identity map on $\mathbb R^2$. Please help.

Comment: Let's see more effort from you. For one thing, it's impossible for us to know what tools/knowledge you have unless you show us. Moreover, your title needs some revision. By the way, "an" identity map makes no sense; there is only one.

Answer (score 1):

Well you dont have much choices for the matrices representations, since a projection can always be written (with the proper bases) as a diagonal matrix with only zeros or one on the diagonal.